# $PQ$ is a projection iff $PQ = QP$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and let $P,Q$ be two projections on some closed subspaces of $H$. Prove that $PQ$ is a projection iff $PQ = QP$.

The direction "if $PQ = QP$ then $PQ$ is a projection" is obvious. Can I get a hint about the second direction?

Thanks

Comment: Are the projections orthogonal?

Comment: @mechanodroid: they have to be,  or the implication does not hold.

Comment: Can we prove it like this? Let $P$ project onto $M$ and $Q$ project onto $N$. Then, since $(M\cap N)^\perp\subseteq M^\perp+N^\perp$, we have the decomposition $H = (M\cap N)+M^\perp+N^\perp$ (the sum not being necessarily direct). This means we can write every $x \in H$ as $x = a + b + c$, for some $a \in M\cap N$, $b\in M^\perp$ and $c\in N^\perp$. Now we see that $PQ(x) = PQ(a + b + c) = P(a + b) = a = Q(a + c) = QP(a + b + c) = QP(x)$

Answer (score 3):

The hint is that $PQ $ is selfadjoint.

Comment: Thanks. I guess we are supposed to solve this without this property, since we didn't learn it yet

Comment: @catch22 What is your definition of projection?  If you don't require self adjoint, do you only require $P^2=P$, or do you have some other definition based on eigenvalues or subspace?

Comment: @Aaron: we'll see what definition the op wants to use. Note that for idempotents the implication is not true, so selfadjoint is required.

Comment: @Aaron: We used $P = P^2$ and $||Px|| \leq ||x||$ for all $x \in H$